# Webapp exiting fullscreen when dragging mui slider in iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, material-ui, slider, mobile-safari

**Link to live example:** https://65fe5550a9ed01a894c38850--gorgeous-pastelito-3de562.netlify.app/

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Open the example in an ipad (chrome or safari) (I tested in 9th and 10th gen ipads)
Go fullscreen (using the Go Fullscreen button in the page)
Try adjusting the blue slider (The page exits fullscreen abruptly)
Current behavior
The page is exiting fullscreen when we drag the slider. This behaviour is happening only when using @mui/material/slider (tested with shadcn slider and native input[type=range] slider. The green slider in the demo page is the native html range slider.

**Expected behavior**
The page should stay in fullscreen while and after changing the value using @mui/material/slider just like how the native implementation works.